Needle nose vise grips with wide opening
Is there such a thing as needle-nose vise grips with a wide opening—wide enough to grab a 2-inch nut (approx) in a tight space?
Yes, needle-nose vise grips can open wide, but it's the tips that open wide. I'm looking for vise grips with a wide opening at the hinge; the jaws would be parallel to the sides of the nut to get a good grip. Similar to a pipe wrench, but much more pointy to fit in tight spaces.
Here's a video that demonstrates the scenario: Dan Wheeler - buying and restoring a 30 year old komatsu PC120 excavator - 1:04:14 (YouTube)

Related: Hold a hitch ball nut in a tight space

In tight spaces where a socket, open/closed box wrench won't fit. Perhaps another idea may help. Inserting large blade screwdrivers as wedges against the nut or bolt head from turning. A space between nut or bolt head determines how thick a wedge is needed to prevent nut/bolt from turning. When using an impact wrench or breaker bar, severely corroded fasteners may create their own 'loctite' and turning a few degrees in both directions can break the bond, working a few degrees more each time to self clean threads. Penetrating fluid helps.

I found a product that might work: "STRONG HAND LOCKING BIG MOUTH C-JAW PLIERS ADJUSTABLE OPENING 6 - 80MM":


https://www.amazon.ca/Strong-Hand-Mouth-Pliers-PAJ100/dp/B0792NN16V/ref=sr_1_5
https://stronghandtools.com/collections/locking-pliers/products/big-mouth-pliers
https://www.hampdon.com.au/strong-hand-locking-big-mouth-c-jaw-pliers-adjustable-opening-6-80mm-paj100


Also, some "Wide Open Locking Pliers":


https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07G2547JR/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o00_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1


If the jaws are too big for either tool, maybe they could be ground down to fit into tight spaces.
